# related laravel attribute value for a specific model

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I am little bit confused regarding my db schema. I have tables for main entity like "motors, motor_attributes" and the attributes are saved in "attribute, attribute_options". The attribute may be input fields, select , checkbox, etc .

Now all the attributes for the motors i am saving it in motor_attributes. And the db structure for the table is

```
Table: id, motor_id, attribute_id, attribute_value ...
```

Now everything is working fine. The problem comes on the listing pages where i will show only two attributes for a single motor.

The second problem is with the attribute values. for select it holds the id of the attribute_options table and for textfield or date type it  holds the 
string data.

How i can get the attribute values.

The relation inside motor Model is like

```
/**********************************/ 
public function adAttributes() { 
    //dd('dd'); 
    return $this->hasMany(MotorAttribute::class,'motor_id','id')
        ->orderBy('motor_id', 'asc');
}
```

And my query for fetching the 20 motors + 2 attributes is like

```
$motors = Motor::with([
    'advertisementPhotos', 
    'customer.dealer', 
    'adAttributes' => function ($query) {
        // $query->with('attribute');
        // $query->with('attributeValue');
        $query->limit(2);
        //;
        //  $query->take(2);
    }
])->where('featured', 1)->where('status', 1)
  ->where('date_expiry', '>=', date('Y-m-d') . ' 00:00:00')
  ->limit(20)->orderBy('position', 'asc');
```

The problem is i can not put limit over the adAttribute also i can not get the exact value. Because the attribute value may be (input field, I can not make relationship) or may be select field(I can make a relation with the attribute_option). and also may be date field(can not make a relationship).

Does the the db need modifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to use `LIMIT` when eager loading, you have to remove `->limit(2)`.

You have to limit the number of attributes after executing the query:

```
foreach($motors as $motor) {
    $motor->adAttributes->take(2);
}
```

**UPDATE:** I've now created a package for eager loading with limit: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit

Comment: I am using vue js.  and i have vue components. That why i need eager loading

Comment: As I said, you can only eager load all attributes, not just the first two.

Comment: you can  not use php code inside vue component. Then how the above your code will work.

Comment: That was just a PHP example. Of couse, in JavaScript you have to use something like `motor.adAttributes.slice(0, 2)`.

Comment: Yes this one is good one. But let say there are 20 items and each item loads with 15 attribute. There should be some mechanism there should be a limit of 2 or three.

Comment: and by the way thanks @Jonas. I solved it by adding the column to the attributes table. that has the 0 1 values. and will only be used on the listing pages. This flag is managed from the admin side. while creating the attributes. So user will mark as true or false. while adding it. And here in the query we will put the where condition like " ->where('show_listing_page', 1)

Comment: I already solved it by adding a flag into the DB table. From backend, we can set that which attributes to display with the single product.(By making that flag to 1 or yes). And here in the relation just take the relation with where clause like

```
  'adAttributes' => function ($query) {
         
        $query->where('flag',1);
    }
])
```
So this condition will take only the same 2 or 3 o4 four attributes with the single item. And query is also optimized means it will not take 15 rows with the single product.

Comment: I've now created a package for eager loading with limit: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit

Comment: Thanks @Jonas Staudenmeir. I will try this on my next project